# memorycache not working in visualstudio debugger

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, memorycache

When executed without debugging, the following code:

```
bool success = cache.Add(cacheKey, ips, policy);
if (success)
{
}
ret = cache[cacheKey] as Dictionary<string, Threat>;
```

works as expected, ret contains the value, and everyone is happy.
But when executed in visual studio debugger, success is true, but ret is null.

I found [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1233ffb3-6480-431b-94ca-1190f96cf5f6/memorycache-get-in-disposed-state-magically?forum=netfxbcl) saying it's a bug in .Net4.0, fixed in 4.5, I am using 4.61 but I am still affected.

In the article they suggest a workaround (for those forced to use 4.0) which it's actually fixing the issue:

```
using (ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow()) {
   // Create memory cache instance under disabled execution context flow             
   return new YourCacheThing.GeneralMemoryCache(…);
}
```

But [in this msdn blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/06/15/executioncontext-vs-synchronizationcontext/) post they say, don't use [`ExecutionContext.SuppressFlow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.executioncontext.suppressflow), it's bad.

So I am little worried about using the workaround, especially because I don't understand why I need it in the first place, since from Net4.5 the bug should be fixed.

Comment: Can you share a simple sample here? As you said that you use .NET 4.61, does it work well if you use the .NET 4.5? If possible, share a simple, I will debug it in my Environment. At least, we could know that whether it is related to the .NET Framework or the debugger tool or others.

Comment: In the mean while I found out using the workaround described it works only the first time in debug, second time it process a request is returning null again. The cache is set, it's just it doesn't seems to be able to read it from the cache just after setting it.